# Three.js smooth rotation in character control

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-development

## Code :

I've written a code that adds character movement to an Object3D in **Three.js**
WASD respectively sets the move forward , left , backward , right variables

- **constants** :

```js
walkinbgSpeed = 5;
rotationSpeed = Math.PI ;
```

- **updateRAF** : passed deltatime in seconds , updates movement position then calls **rotate**

```js
 updateRAF(dts) {
        if (this.moveForward) {
            this.model.position.z += this.walkinbgSpeed * dts;
            this.rotate(dts, 0)
        }
        if (this.moveBackward) {
            this.model.position.z -= this.walkinbgSpeed * dts;
            this.rotate(dts, Math.PI)
        }
        if (this.moveLeft) {
            this.model.position.x += this.walkinbgSpeed * dts;
            this.rotate(dts, Math.PI/2)
        }
        if (this.moveRight) {
            this.model.position.x -= this.walkinbgSpeed * dts;
            this.rotate(dts, -Math.PI/2)
        }

    }
```

- **rotate** : smoothly rotates an Object3D by gradually increments the **interpolation factor t** + using the quaternion **slep function** directly on the **model's quaternion**

```js
 rotate(dts, angle) {
        let t = 0;

        const animateRotation = () => {
            t += this.rotationSpeed * dts;

            if (t >= 1) {
                t = 1; // Clamp t to ensure it doesn't exceed 1
            }

            const qb = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), angle);

            this.model.quaternion.slerp(qb, t);

            if (t < 1) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animateRotation); // Continue animation if not finished
            }
        };

        requestAnimationFrame(animateRotation);
    }
```

## Problem :

- Pressing one direction at a time rotates the model smoothly as intended
- Combining two direction buttons starts with a smooth rotation , ends up insta-rotating the model in the last held button direction with no smoothness applied

## Note :

- If needed full code can be provided
- Any help is greatly appreciated